# Find the units of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find the units of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Q$.

Let $x,y \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$. Then $xy = (a,b) \cdot(c,d) = (ac,bd)$, where $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb Z$. Now $$(ac,bd)=(1,1) \iff ac=1, bd=1.$$ We have that $ac=1 \iff a=1,c=1$ or $a=c^{-1}$ or $c=a^{-1}.$ The same holds for $bd=1  \iff b=1,d=1$ or $b=d^{-1}$ or $d=b^{-1}.$

Now pick $x,y \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Q$. Then $xy=(a,q) \cdot (b,r) = (ab,qr)$, where $a,b\in \Bbb Z$ and $q,r \in \Bbb Q$. Now $$(ab,qr)=(1,1) \iff ab=1, qr=1.$$ For $ab=1$ we need to have that $a=1,b=1$ or $a=b^{-1}$ or $b=a^{-1}$. What can I do for $qr=1$? Should I express $q$ and $r$ as a fraction of coprime elements and then see when the multiplication evaluates to $1$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ and $S$ be rings. Then we always have for the groups of units that
$$(R\times S)^\times = R^\times\times S^\times$$
This just follows from the definition of direct products, i.e., of the multiplication of elements of a direct product.